# Storing string in an array using: Mongoose, MongoDB, and mongoose-simpleDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my schema I have the following specified:

```
Links: []
```

On a post I have the following (the following is node.js):

```
app.post('/add', function (req, res) {

    var newItem = new db.Item({
    Links[0]: req.body.Link1
    Links[1]: req.body.Link2
    });

    newItem.save(function () {
        res.send("saved");
    });
});
```

I get an unexpected token error for the "[".

What should I be doing differently? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote. If the down voter wanted to explain that would actually be constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object notation is not correct. You need:

```
app.post('/add', function (req, res) {

    var newItem = new db.Item({
        Links: [  req.body.Link1, req.body.Link2 ]
    });

    newItem.save(function () {
        res.send("saved");
    });
});
```

Or:

```
app.post('/add', function (req, res) {

    var newItem = new db.Item();
    newItem.Links.push(req.body.Link1);
    newItem.Links.push(req.body.Link2);

    newItem.save(function () {
        res.send("saved");
    });
});
```